# How can do something similiar to this with css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to get a grid layout with 6 elements centered on the page like the following:
[image]

But I cannot get the grid is center with images, any idea?

```css
   
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
      background-color: #999999;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      &.one{
       background-image: url("img/mainmeu/e.png");
     }
      &.two{
       background-image: url("img/mainmeu/b.png");
      }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item one">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item two">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item three">3</div>  
      <div class="grid-item four">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item five">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item six">6</div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate? What part is not centered? Or is the problem related to the images?

Comment: check the updated ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `column-gap` and `row-gap` for grid spacing.
2. Use `background-image` properties to center the image inside grid box

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: #999;
    column-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    row-gap: 30px;
    justify-items: left;
    align-items: center;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    align-content: center;
    display: inline-grid;
}

.grid-item.one {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x200");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.grid-item.two {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200x200");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item one">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item two">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item three">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item four">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item five">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item six">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The layout is attached to the left edges of the screen, instead of being a centered grid

Answer (score 2):

Just use `justify-content: center` to center the *grid items*. Also use a `grid-gap` values to get the required layout. See demo below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #999999;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px; /* added */
  grid-column-gap: 10px; /* added */
  justify-content: center; /* added */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200");
  background-size: cover; /* image as cover */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item one">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item two">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item three">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item four">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item five">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item six">6</div>
</div>
```

If you want to vary the *grid item* sizes, you can the relative dimensions using `padding` (because its always based on width). In the below demo I've used `padding-top: 60%` (if you use 100% you will get a square *grid item*):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #999999;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px; /* added */
  grid-column-gap: 10px; /* added */
  justify-content: center; /* added */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200");
  background-size: cover; /* image as cover */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* added width */
  width: 20vw;
  /* center inner content using flexbox */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-item:after {
  padding-top: 60%; /* according to your aspect ratio */
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item one">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item two">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item three">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item four">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item five">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item six">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't setting sizes, use `inline-grid` and center that using `text-align:center` on the parent.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #999999;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item one">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item two">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item three">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item four">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item five">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item six">6</div>
</div>
```